# Linq query to get disjoint set in a many to many relation

Tags: c#, linq

In my application i manage Persons which are assigned to Users, the type of association is many to many becasuse a Person can be assigned to  more than one User. So I have the following tables.

User Table:

UserID

Person Table:

PersonID

(Union Table managed by Entity Framework,  not visible from Linq query)

PersonApplicationUser Table: 

UserID 

PersonID

I want to retrieve the set of persons that are not assigned to any user. So far i can get the set of Persons not assigned to the currently logged in user this way

```
var query = db.Persons.Except(user.Persons);
```

Unfortunatly it  will retrieve the Persons assigned to others users too and that is not  correct, i thing that Except is the way to go but need advice with it.

EDIT:
The main difficult i find is that i cannot access union table PersonApplicationUser from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
db.Persons.Where(p => !p.Users.Any())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.Persons.Where(p => p.Users.Count() == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is aware that relations are just like collections, so you can perform collection operations and EF will transform them into the relevant sql.

What you want is something like this:

```
var query =  from p in db.Persons
             where !p.Users.Any()
             select p;
```

Or in method syntax:

```
var query = db.Persons.Where(p => !p.Users.Any());
```